# Assigning node names to a graph in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, networkx

I'm trying to generate a networkx graph from a dataframe using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

data = [[0,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], [1,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4'])
df.index = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']

G = nx.DiGraph(df.values, with_labels=True)
nx.draw(G)
```

However, the graphs outputs without the names of the node being shown, which looks like below

[image: Networkx]

I tried to label the nodes in the graph using the networkx `relabel_nodes` however without luck

```
G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, dict(enumerate(df.columns)))
nx.draw(G)
```

Is there a way wherein I can label the nodes of the networkx graph as `S1, S2, S3, S4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The renaming should be a mapping that has old node identifiers as keys and new node identifier as values (a dictionary, basically):

```py
mapping = {0: "S1", 1: "S2", 2: "S3", 3: "S4"}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
print(H.nodes)
# ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
```

Comment: Thanks ! A quick question: Is there a way wherein the above-generated graph can be exported to Plotly ?